# How can i detect that there is a VOIP call running by code?

Tags: android, voip, microphone

hi iam having an application that transfer alot of data using WiFi within a background service, what i want is when there is a VOIP call i want to stop this service.

how can i detect when there is a VOIP call?? i had think that i can see if the External Mic is in use and there is no GSM call, but i dont know how to detect if the external Mic is in use.
all i find is how to use the Mic like this `myAudioRecord.startRecording();`i want to detect if it is already in use.can any one help me? and if there are any better ideas to detect a VOIP call i will appreciate it.
thanks in advance

Comment: First thing that comes to mind (just an idea, could be wrong) is to take a list of all commercial VoIP protocols http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP#Protocols; have a list of the default ports for communication, and monitor the traffic there.

Comment: do you have any i idea how can i detect if the Mic is in use?

Comment: I don't know, but shouldn't this class serve you well? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html